# extracting data from another webpage using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I don't even know whether it is possible or not but here goes my question
I have a dynamic page created by CI. now there is another page on another server which is static. The other page has a basic table which is also static. Now I want to load that other page from my webpage. is it possible when both pages are located on different servers? If yes can anyone guide me

thanks in advance
~muttalebm

Comment: I guess its possible with iframes but im looking for an alternative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and grab the HTML from the page and just echo it out, or if you want to customize that HTML use PHP's [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to extract the portion you want (table) and then echo it out. Btw make sure you have [allow_url_fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) set to on, otherwise you will not be able to grab the remote content.

Comment: Thanks for the reply cryptic. Just need another help. Do I need to use the allow_url_fopen option on the other server or on the one that I'm working with? and is it possible to get the data of that table in an array or something without modifying the codes at the other end? I need to clear something that the table that want IS open for all. the problem is that I cannot change it (html code)

Comment: @muttalebm The one that will be performing the remote grabbing. The one being grabbed from will not matter.

Comment: Thanks a lot cryptic I will try that tomorrow and hopefully let you know how it goes

Comment: Hey Cryptic, just wanted you to know that it worked. Thank you very much for your help. Really appriciate it.