# How can I fetch contents of other websites and display it in my website using codeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

Process.php

```
            <?php
            defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

            class Process extends CI_Controller {

                public function index()
                {
                    $this->load->view('process');
                    //echo "test";
                }   
            }
```

process.php

```
            <?php
            $curl = curl_init();
            $auth_data = array(
                'client_id'         => '30b5f5beeccfba1dbcb31941523d5e3b',
                'client_secret'     => ' ', 
                'grant_type'        => 'client_credentials'
            );

            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $auth_data);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://authentication.skimapis.com/access_token'); //https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

            $result = curl_exec($curl);
            if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
            echo $result;
            curl_close($curl);

            ?>
```

****Browser view**** 
               415 Unsupported Media Type
                The server does not support the media type transmitted in the request.
       How to solve this issue

Comment: you can find answer here .. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4624368/8393415

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP CURL to CodeIgniter controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622331/php-curl-to-codeigniter-controller)

Comment: You can find the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995244/extracting-data-from-another-webpage-using-codeigniter